# Running python manage.py run_huey in production

Tags: django, web-deployment, digital-ocean, python-3.8, python-huey

I recently deployed a django web app using Ubuntu 20.04, gunicorn and nginx, Huey was implemented which worked perfectly locally. At production, **I need to run python manage.py run_huey using systemd**.

I've tried the suggestion here [Can't enable huey service on deploy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501317/cant-enable-huey-service-on-deploy-server) but not working.

My code is similar to that suggestion. I will appreciate any contribution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by adding **Requires=gunicorn.socket** to the code. Now my huey.service looks

```
[Unit]
Description=Huey Service
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=redis.service

[Service]
User=deploy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/username/projectdir
ExecStart=/home/username/projectdir/env/bin/python manage.py run_huey
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After that I ran sudo systemctl start gunicorn.sock. It worked but showing active:dead which I don't like

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used supervisord to run huey
I put supervisord.conf /home/user. It looks like this

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; the path to the socket file
chmod=0700                 ; socket file mode (default 0700)
chown=user:user       ; socket file uid:gid owner


[supervisord]
logfile=/home/user/supervisord.log ; main log file; default $CWD/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=1MB        ; max main logfile bytes b4 rotation; default 50MB
logfile_backups=5           ; # of main logfile backups; 0 means none, default 10
loglevel=info                ; log level; default info; others: debug,warn,trace
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; supervisord pidfile; default supervisord.pid
nodaemon=false               ; start in foreground if true; default false
silent=false                 ; no logs to stdout if true; default false
minfds=1024                  ; min. avail startup file descriptors; default 1024
minprocs=200                 ; min. avail process descriptors;default 200
childlogdir=/home/medsjoin            ; 'AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface


[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[program:huey]
command=python manage.py run_huey              ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
directory=/home/user/projectdir; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
stdout_logfile_backups=2     ; # of stdout logfile backups (0 means none, default 10)
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
stderr_logfile_backups=2     ; # of stderr logfile backups (0 means none, default 10)
environment =
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="special.settings",
  PYTHONPATH="/home/user/projectdir/special",
  PATH="/home/user/projectdir/env/bin:%(ENV_PATH)s"
```

I started that with supervisord.service located in /etc/systemd/system/supervisord.service

```
[Unit]
Description=supervisord daemon
Documentation=http://supervisord.org
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/supervisord -n -c /home/user/supervisord.conf
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /home/user/supervisord.conf reload
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -c /home/user/supervisord.conf shutdown

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then start the service with

```
sudo systemctl start supervisord.service
```

Check status by

```
sudo systemctl status supervisord.service
```

You may also need to run

```
sudo systemctl enable supervisord
```

Note user rep my user, projectdir: where my django project is located, project: my django project